# trying to filter the rows that has 'Restaurants' in categories column

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, anonymous-function

I am trying to filter the rows to only that has the restaurant in the categories column using lambdas.

I came across the below piece of code that will get the work done.

```
business = business.loc[business['categories'].apply(lambda x: 'Restaurants' in x), :]
```

However, I am having difficulty understanding the lambda function. I was able to run the code without lambda.

```
def process(data):
    mask = []
    for i in range(10):
        if 'Restaurants' in data[i]:
            mask.append(True)
        else:
            mask.append(False)
    return mask

business_updated = process(business['categories'])
business['categories'][business_updated]
```

i got the desired result using functions, but i dont understand the lambda part

Thanks,

[image: Business dataFrame]

Comment: What don't you understand?  If you search in your browser for "Python lambda function", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.  If you also search for uses with "apply" you should find some examples.  What wasn't clear from those?

Answer (score 1):

The lambda function (`lambda x: 'Restaurants' in x`) is exactly equivalent to this:

```
def lambdafunc(x):
    return "Restaurants" in x
```

As you can see, what is in the left of the colon (`:`) represents the input and what is in the right represents the returned value. As simple as that. Refer to the following link for extra information about lambda functions: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda